# using 2 jquery widgets in one page

Tags: jquery

This might be the dumbest question but I cant find an answer.

How do I reference 2 jquery widgets in 1 page.  Should it be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('#ReleaseDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
    $(document).tooltip();
});
```

or like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('#ReleaseDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });

});

$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip();

});
```

Or is it a different way as I cant get it working either eay.

Comment: The first one should be fine.

Comment: the '$(function () {' is used once, its document ready , you call it twice, as j08691 has said, the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both would do the trick, but the first one would be my preference, since it would let me write-less-do-more!

You can use/prefer the first one, it has less lines. But will give you the same output as the second code. Because it has less lines, so it would be more preferred.

Please remember, to **write-less-do-more**.

Comment: Not sure does not the second document ready set the name space over writing the second ? Curious, I should just try it.. eh.